# I18n translated values do not show up if changed from helper method rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

Hello not sure how to explain this but i will give it my best shot.

I hv a model like this

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMPLOYMENT_TYPE = [
    ['Employed', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.employed')],
    ['Self-Employed', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.self_employed')],
    ['Unemployed / Retired', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.unemployed')]
  ]
end
```

I also have a helper method that calls this

```
module AnswerHelper
  def get_employment_type_list
    return Answer::EMPLOYMENT_TYPE
  end
end
```

And a partial view that should display the values like this

_step_1.html.erb

```
<% employment_list = get_employment_type_list %>
<%= employment_list %>
<div class="flex_center flex_column button-wrap">
  <%= collection_radio_buttons("application[answer_attributes]", :employment_type, employment_list, :first, :last, item_wrapper_tag: false, checked: @selected_employment_type) do |b|
    b.label(class: 'employment_type_radio') { b.radio_button(:onchange => "return_employment_type(value)", class:'radio-label')  + b.label(class:'button-label'){b.text}}
  end %>
</div>
```

_step_2.html.erb

```
<% employer_list = get_employer_list(chosen_employment_type(@decoded_self_evaluation)) %>
<% employer_type = @decoded_self_evaluation.try(:loan_application).try(:kyc_answer).try(:employer_type) %>
<div class="flex_center flex_column button-wrap">
  <%= collection_radio_buttons("loan_application[kyc_answer_attributes]", :employer_type, employer_list, :first, :last, item_wrapper_tag: false, checked: employer_type) do |b|
    b.label(class: 'employer_type_radio') { b.radio_button(:onchange => "is_business_registered(value)", class:'radio-label') + b.label(class:'button-label'){b.text}}
  end %>
</div>
```

identity.js

```
$.ajax({
    url:'/self_evaluations/' + self_evaluation_id + '/employment_type',
    method:"POST",
    data:JSON.stringify({employment_type: employment_type, key: $('#token_key').val()}),
    contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType:"script",
    async: false,
    success: function(data) {
      $valid = true;
    }
  })
```

employment_list.js.erb

```
$('#id_employer').empty();
$('#id_employer').append("<%=j render 'self_evaluations/self_evaluation_partials/step_2' %>");
```

Now the problem is that i have already added all that's needed for I18n translations to happen in Rails and for texts that are translated on the html view it works correctly when i switch from the different languages but for texts that are been gotten via a helper method like this. Based on initial help, on initial load, all page work fine but if i change the language and then run an ajax call that loads the employment_list.js.erb my locale seems to still be the primary language the the values do not change accordingly

Not sure why this is happening anyone faced something like this before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you declared the translations as a constant in your model, so the translations were loaded just one time when `Answer` model was loaded in the first time.

In `production` environment, the model will be loaded after starting server. In `development` environment, the model will be loaded when the file content is changed, ...

In order to solve your issue, you can add the translations in your helper instead:

```
module AnswerHelper
  def get_employment_type_list
    [
      ['Employed', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.employed')],
      ['Self-Employed', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.self_employed')],
      ['Unemployed / Retired', I18n.t('self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status.unemployed')]
    ]
  end
end
```

---

I usually use this approach, please have a look!

```
class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  EMPLOYMENT_TYPE = [:employed, :self_employed, :unemployed_or_retired]
end

module AnswerHelper
  def get_employment_type_list
    i18n_scope = 'self_evaluation.self_evaluation_form.employment_status'

    Answer::EMPLOYMENT_TYPE.map do |type|
      [type, t(type, scope: i18n_scope)]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: hi @fongfan999 your suggestion works but with an exception. i have updated my initial question to explain it better

Comment: Hi @KingsleySimon, What was your exception?

Comment: i have updated in the question. Basically if u can in step_1.html.erb, there is an onchange method that when called makes an ajax call to a method that then loads the employment.js.erb file. In the employment.js.erb file, i am emptying a page and appending it back again but because of that somehow the locale goes back to the default locale and hence translated value is still based on default locale

Comment: How did you get current locale? params[:locale]? subdomain? ...?

Comment: Basically, you need to pass your current locale, then translate your employment types by using [I18n.with_locale](https://translation.io/blog/rails-i18n-with-locale) to switch to the current locale.